# Turning off debugging shortcuts

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I am examining a package by debugging in RStudio and there are objects I would like to examine - so I type the name into the console. However if the name starts with one of `s`,`f`,`c` or `q` then a debugging action is carried out as these correspond to the shortcuts.

i.e. If I want to see the contents of object `q` I type `q` and the debugger ends as this is the shortcut for `quit`

Is it possible to turn off these shortcuts or perhaps reassign them to something like `alt + q` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These shortcuts are hard-coded into R itself, so you can't change or reassign them in RStudio.

However, it's easy to work around the problem: just use `get("s")` instead of `s`. E.g.:

```
> s <- 12
```

Now entering the debugger and typing <kbd>s</kbd> steps out:

```
> browser()
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> s
>
```

Using `get("s")` to see the value:

```
> browser()
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> get("s")
[1] 12
```